# How to update nested object documents in mongoDB by nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

here is my model:

```
const FamilySchema = new Schema(
userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    default: null
},
familyLocation: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: null
},
father: {
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: null
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: null,
        enum: [null, 'Employed', 'Business']
    }
},
mother: {
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: null
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: null,
        enum: [null, 'Employed', 'Business']
    },
},
nativePlace: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: null
},{
timestamps: true})
```

Now i want to update any of its fields. here is my API so far:

```
const UpdateFamilyDetails = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    let queryObject = req.body
    let filteredObject = {}
    let id = req.user.id

    //Remove null fields of the req.body object
    for (const key in queryObject) {
        if (`${queryObject[key]}` != 'null') {
            filteredObject[key] = `${queryObject[key]}`
        }
    }
    let finalObject = ModifyObject(filteredObject)
    
    const result = await FamilyInfo.findOneAndUpdate({ userId: id },
        { $set: { finalObject }}, { new: true }).exec()
    if ( !result ) {
        return res.status(501).json({
            status: false,
            message: 'Internal server error'
        })
    }
    res.status(201).json({ status: true, data: result });
} catch (error) {
    if (error)
        next(error)
}
```

}

And I just made the **finalObject** using this methods:

```
const ModifyObject = obj => {

const { familyLocation, fatherName, fatherStatus,motherName, motherStatus, nativePlace } = obj

let data = {}

if (fatherName || fatherStatus) {
    data.father = {}
    if (fatherName) {
        data.father.name = fatherName
    }
    if (fatherStatus) {
        data.father.status = fatherStatus
    }
}
if (motherName || motherStatus) {
    data.mother = {}
    if (motherName) {
        data.mother.name = motherName
    }
    if (motherStatus) {
        data.mother.status = motherStatus
    }
}
if (familyLocation) {
    data.familyLocation = familyLocation
}
return data }
```

So what is the proper and efficient way to update any of the fields as req.body object? just keep in mind that if **req.body** has only familyLocation and  **fatherName** and then only the familyLocation and father name value will be updated and other values will not be effected.Thank you.

Comment: Not really understanding what you're asking, but the proper way to update just the father name is { $set: { "father.name" : "new name" }}

Comment: i don't want to update only father name, i want to update the models fields accroding to my req.body object.  and wich fields is not in the req.body object ,does not get effected.